# Double pointer difference when using with array

Tags: c++

Is there a difference between the following two lines and if so what is it? (in C++)

```
float (**a[10]);
float *(*a[10]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Try

```
float (**a[10]);
float *(*b[10]);
if (typeid(a) == typeid(b))
    printf("==\n");
else
    printf("!=\n");
```

The output is

```
==
```